# Recommendations for Free Linux monitoring tools

Tags: opensuse, monitoring

My Linux version is `Linux 3.4.76-65.111.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64`. It's AWS.

These days I'm suffering from the absence of monitoring tools, processes sometimes die without knowing it.

My need is simple.
Though they might be achieved by my own shell script, I want it managed by tools.

1. Alert if specific processes die
2. Alert if resource(hard disk space, CPU, MEMORY) reaches to treshold
3. Tracking resource usage
4. Free for corporation use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use Nagios.  In a survey I did awhile back I noticed that this was a big majority favorite.  Notice that a lot of sites use multiple monitoring tools.

I'd like to remind you that "free" only means that the source code is available, effort (in any case) is still required and that is NOT free.

BTW, Nagios comes in a free and a paid supported version.

Answer (score 2):

`Zabbix` is the first one that comes to mind. It's what I'm using at home. It can alert on resource utilisation, processes, has historical tracking. Note that it needs an agent installed on the server.

Alternatively, `Cacti` can also do what you need through plugins for alerting.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) and its variations.